# How does application Initialization in IIS work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I configured my IIS website to be always up and to initialize it after pool recycle. But I'm not sure how it works. This is .NET 6 MVC app.

All instructions say that I need to install **Application Initialization role**, but **"Preload enabled"** setting was available for my website even before installing this role. I set it to **true** but it didn't seem to work. I installed Application Initialization and it started working.

So the first question is what does "Preload enabled" setting do when you don't have Application Initialization installed?

I assume that with above settings IIS is making a request to my Home page. But I'm not sure I will have this page in final version of application.

The second question is, if I remove Home page will auto preloading stop working? If yes, then I need to use **applicationInitialization** settings in config file and configure it like this?

`<add initializationPage="/CustomWarmupPage" hostName="myhost" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the first question is what does "Preload enabled" setting do when
> you don't have Application Initialization installed?

Starting with IIS 8, application initialization is part of the IIS feature set. For IIS 7 and 7.5, it is available as a separate download through the Web Platform Installer. Application initialization with IIS 8 is an optional installation component in Windows or Windows Server Role Manager.

To support application initialization on your Web server, you must install the Application Initialization role or feature. If application initialization is not installed, the "Preload enabled" setting will have no effect.

> The second question is, if I remove Home page will auto preloading
> stop working? If yes, then I need to use applicationInitialization
> settings in config file and configure it like this?
>
> `<add initializationPage="/CustomWarmupPage" hostName="myhost" />`

The way this module works is that you introduce a path, and when your ApplicationPool runs, it sends a request to the registered path. System startup should not be delayed until the first request is sent to the program. To do this, you must enter the following command in the system.webServer tag of the web.config file,like:

```
 <applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true"
 skipManagedModules="true" >
   <add initializationPage="/default.aspx" />
 </applicationInitialization>
```

Using the above command, we specify that after the ApplcationPool starts, it will send a "/default.aspx" request to the path entered in the initializationPage parameter, which is the initial setup of the service. Then you need to set the Application Pool Start Mode value to AlyawsRunning and the WebSite PreLoad Enebled value to true to do this automatically. This will always send a request to warm up the app when the app starts or restarts.

Comment: Thank you. One more question. I didn't add anything in web.config or applicatioHost.config and it still worked. Installing "Application Initialization" and setting PreloadEnabled=true 
 was enough. Does this mean that by default it makes request to default Url of website and in my case hits /Home/Index MVC action?

Comment: Yes, the web.config settings is optional, if you don't provide it IIS hits the default site link (/). when you set the Preload Enabled to true, the ASP.NET application should load automatically. If you just want your website to start automatically, this is all you need to preload your website. But if you want more control over the loading process, you can add more settings to the web.config file that allow you to display a static page when the application starts. This can be useful if startup is really slow, you can display a static HTML page instead of a blank screen while the user waits.